# how do I disable all angular animations except 1?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular 9 app that makes significant use of mat-tab-group. I want to disable all animations related to switching tabs, as well as the transitions that occur with the stepper (which seems it may be just an extension of the tab view).

However, Im using an accordion view where I would like to have animations enabled. It seems that when I declare `@HostBinding('@.disabled')` on a component, all sub components have disabled animations. The problem Im having is that the accordion view is a subcomponent within a tab view that I wish to not animate. Is there a way to "white list" components to be animated?

Answer (score 2):

For the tabs component, you can make use of the `animationDuration` input.

From the [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview#controlling-the-tab-animation):

> You can control the duration of the tabs' animation using the `animationDuration` input. *If you want to disable the animation completely, you can do so by setting the properties to 0ms.*

<sub>(Emphasis is mine)</sub>

Here's an example, taken directly from the same documentation:

```html
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
  <mat-tab label="First">Content 1</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">Content 2</mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">Content 3</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

As for the other components, AFAIK there's no easy way of disabling animations that I can think of without disabling other animations inside of the components.

Comment: Edric I actually tried that... so in my UI I have a top level tab view, and a couple of the tabs have a tab view within them. it seems like the animationDuration works the first time I navigate to one of those inner tabs. But if I navigate to another top level tab, and back down, that animation value gets reset. Maybe theres something weird with the lifecycle of the Dom that im not handling?